# How to read from Registers with pymodbus

Tags: python, modbus

how can I read from Register with pymodbus?

I'm trying this piece of code:

```
import pymodbus
from pymodbus.pdu import ModbusRequest
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient 
#initialize a serial RTU client instance
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer

#count= the number of registers to read
#unit= the slave unit this request is targeting
#address= the starting address to read from

client = ModbusClient(method = 'rtu', port='/dev/extcomm/0/0', stopbits = 1, bytesize = 8, parity = 'N' , baudrate= 38400)

#Connect to the serial modbus server
 connection = client.connect()
 print(connection)

#Starting add, num of reg to read, slave unit.
coil  = client.read_holding_registers(0x01,1,unit=1)# address, count, 
slave address
print(coil)

#Closes the underlying socket connection
client.close()
```

This gave me this error:

```
    Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received)
```

My slave id is number 1 and the register I want to read is also the number 1, but i don't know why is still doesn't want to work.

Comment: Check your communication settings (baudrate, partiy etc) ,also experiment with timeout (`ModbusClient(..., timeout=2)) , some devices are slow to respond.

Answer (score 4):

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient

client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='COM4', baudrate=2400, timeout=1)

client.connect()
read=client.read_holding_registers(address = 222 ,count =10,unit=1) 
//Address is register address e.g 30222, 
//and count is number of registers to read, 
//so it will read values of register 30222 to 30232
//unit is slave address, for 1 device leave it 1

data=read.registers[int(2)] #reading register 30223 
print(data) #printing value read in above line
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me as well:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient

client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='COM5', baudrate=9600, timeout=0.5)

client.connect()
read=client.read_holding_registers(address = 0x00,
                                 count =65,
                                 unit=1)

data=read.registers[int(64)] #read register id 64
print(data) #print register data
```

Maybe you should try this:

```
print(coil.registers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most Likely the error you received was due to the fact that the serial port is accessed with another application or the previous execution of the code never released or closed the communication. Disconnect and Reconnect the device and that should solve this error. Verify that recoonected port same as in your code.

As Holub Dávid mentioned you should be accessing the coil.registers but printing them as suggested would miss one value.  The values in coil are coil.registers[0], coil.registers[1], coil.registers[2], ....coil.registers[n-1] for n values.

For some reason print(coil.registers) is providing values excluding the first.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please format code as such with 2 quotation marks like that: 

`` ``some code snippet here`` ``